# Use dynamic directive name in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have following different data types and for each data types I have corresponding directives

1. text
2. email
3. audio
4. video
5. image

Currently based on the data types I have if/else logic and calling the corresponding directive.

Can I call directive name dynamically to avoid the if/else?

Following is my current code

```
<emptyelement data-ng-if="column.type === 'string' && !column.isDropdown">
  <label class="admin-mandatory-field"><span data-ng-if="!getValue(column)">*</span></label>
  <input data-ng-readonly="!column.editable" type="text" class="form-control admin-textbox" data-ng-model="resource[column.name]"  placeholder="{{column.displayName}}" title="{{column.displayName}}" name="textBox{{column.name}}" required/>
  <!--Error message on violation-->
  <div class="custom-error" data-ng-show="resourceAddEditFormName['textBox{{column.name}}'].$dirty && resourceAddEditFormName['textBox{{column.name}}'].$invalid">* <span data-ng-show="resourceAddEditFormName['textBox{{column.name}}'].$error.required" data-ng-bind-template="{{column.displayName}}' is invalid.'"></span></div>
</emptyelement>
  <emptyelement data-ng-if="column.type === 'string' && column.isDropdown">
  <label class="admin-mandatory-field"><span data-ng-if="!getValue(column)">*</span></label>
  <multidropdown class="admin-textbox" data-selected-id-list="getSelectedIdListForDropdown(column)" data-dropdown="column"></multidropdown>               
</emptyelement>
<emptyelement data-ng-if="column.type === 'address'">
  <addresseditor   data-address="getValue(column)" data-column="column" data-collection-admin="collectionAdmin"></addresseditor>               
</emptyelement>
<emptyelement data-ng-if="column.type === 'object'">
  <label class="admin-mandatory-field"><span data-ng-if="!getValue(column)">*</span></label>
  <input data-ng-readonly="!column.editable" type="text" class="form-control admin-textbox" data-ng-model="resource[column.name]"  placeholder="{{column.displayName}}" title="{{column.displayName}}" name="textBox{{column.name}}" required/>
  <!--Error message on violation-->
  <div class="custom-error" data-ng-show="resourceAddEditFormName['textBox{{column.name}}'].$dirty && resourceAddEditFormName['textBox{{column.name}}'].$invalid">* <span data-ng-show="resourceAddEditFormName['textBox{{column.name}}'].$error.required" data-ng-bind-template="{{column.displayName}}' is invalid.'"></span></div>
</emptyelement>
```

How can i invoke directive name using variable? I can pass the subset of data variable to directive.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

[AngularJS Dynamic Directives inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817975/angularjs-dynamic-directives-inside-ng-repeat)

Here it talks about changing dynamically a directive inside a `ng-repeat`, but the idea is the same; changing directive via its name by dynamic vars.